# ngInfiniteScroll resulting in TypeError: Cannot read property 'Scroll' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, nginfinitescroll

I'm working with Angular integrated with Firebase and I'm trying to achieve a infinite scrolling in my application.

So I'm struggling to use the [ngInfiniteScroll](https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll) in my page. Following [this documentation](http://firebase.github.io/firebase-util/#/toolbox/Paginate/example/ngInfiniteScroll) I start facing `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Scroll' of undefined angular.js:13236` error message.

```
(function (angular) {
  "use strict";

  var app = angular.module('myApp.baby', ['firebase', 'firebase.utils', 'firebase.auth', 'ngRoute', 'infinite-scroll']);

  app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/:babyId', {
        templateUrl: 'baby/baby.html',
        controller: 'BabyController',
    });
  }]);

  app.controller('BabyController', ['$scope', 'Auth', 'fbutil', 'FBURL', '$location', '$firebaseObject', '$routeParams', '$firebaseArray',
    function($scope, Auth, fbutil, FBURL, $location, $firebaseObject, $routeParams, $firebaseArray) {
      $scope.FBURL = FBURL;

      var unbind;

      var baby = $firebaseObject(fbutil.ref('babies', $routeParams.babyId));
      baby.$bindTo($scope, 'baby').then(function(ub) { unbind = ub; });

      var baseRef = new Firebase(FBURL).child("posts");
      var scrollRef = new Firebase.util.Scroll(baseRef, 'number');
      $scope.items = $firebaseArray(scrollRef);
      $scope.items.scroll = scrollRef.scroll;
    }
  ]);

})(angular);
```

posts.html

```
<div infinite-scroll="items.scroll.next(10)" infinite-scroll-distance="1">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{item.$id}}: {{item.number}}, {{item.string}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is the data displaying with your ng-repeat?

Comment: @comoss no, nothing is happening in the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complaint here is that `Firebase.util` is undefined. Most likely, you've failed to include the library via a script tag or you've included things in the wrong order and it's not available at the time your code is invoked.

The code in the question doesn't provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and the error has nothing to do with the code presented here, so there is some guesswork involved in answering this.

Comment: Ok, and what else would be helpful to be included here? And what do you mean by `included things in wrong order`? What should be included first or last?

Comment: I'm not going to be much help here if you don't know what `<script>` tags are or how to include them. `Firebase.util` doesn't exist at the time you've tried to use it. To make it exist, you have to include it, and you have to do so before you try to use it.